# Add custom Eloquent ORM models to WHMCS version 6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, composer-php, whmcs

WHMCS version 6 uses the [Eloquent model](http://blog.whmcs.com/?t=98138).

Their [using models documentation](http://docs.whmcs.com/Using_Models) clearly states how to access the WHMCS database.

The problem I am experiencing is that I want to access my own model. I have multiple models, some that access WHMCS directly, and other that access a completely separate database.

To use their model, you do this:
`...
use WHMCS\User\Client;
...`

I tried simply to do this:

`...
use WHMCS\User\Client;
use Radius\User\Logon;
...`

I added my models to $root_folder/includes/classes/Radius/User/Logon.php mimicking the folder structure of WHMCS.

However, I get an error `Fatal error: Class 'Radius\User\Logon' not found in /var/www/vhosts/snowball.co.za/wh6.snowball.co.za/modules/servers/radius/radius.php on line 543`

I fully suspect I have to update Composer to recognise my own models, but I am not sure. What I do needs to be fully integrated with WHMCS and it must not break anything.

Does anyone have advice?

Comment: You may need to update your autoloaders.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Which autoloader are you referring to? I count `autoload_classmap.php`, `autoload_files.php`, `autoload_namespaces.php`, `autoload_psr4.php`, `autoload_real.php`, `ClassLoader.php`, `autoload.php`. Do I also have to do some kind of composer update?

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` to rebuild those

Comment: Hi @BenSwinburne, thanks, you simple answer has gotten me much further. It seems I have a lot to do. I followed this tutorial https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/create-composer-package and set up a basic Github repository.

I notice no composer.json file in WHMCS root, only whmcs.composer.lock in vendor folder. I copy this file to root and rename it to composer.json. I haven't made my additions to composer.json yet, and just test by running composer update. Then it erases most of the existing files! I have some reading to do with how composer.json, composer.lock interact.

Comment: Hi @user2182349, please answer this question so that I can award the bounty.It turns out that the short cut is to add requisite files to the vendor folder, and then just update autoload_psr4.php. I copied what was done in autoload_ps4.php for WHMCS and ended up with:

`'Snowball\\' => array($vendorDir . '/snowball'),`

I realise the technically correct ways of updating Composer but I suspect the WHMCS installation is minimalist so I very much prefer this manual method for now. Even though I didn't properly respond to your comment in retrospect you have guided me to fruition and you were first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to update your autoloaders.

Thank you for posting the solution - others will no doubt appreciate it.